# Price Tier Effective Date

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I don't understand in iTunes the meaning of Price Tier Effective Date and Price Tier End Date. Please anyone could explain me these fields?

Comment: I believe this question is off topic for SO. Questions should really relate to software development, not marketing or distribution. In an effort to be helpful I've provided an answer below. Note that if you have an iTunesConnect account you could easily have looked the answer up yourself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The meanings of those fields are clearly spelled out in the "Scheduling Price Tier Changes" section of the current the [*iTunesConnect Developer Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html). Briefly, they refer to the beginning and end date for a price change. For example, you could set your app to change to a different price on the first of the month, and then to go back to the previous price on the 15th of the month (or any other date).

Comment: ..and effort that should not remain without reward... +1 for kindness.

Comment: @Caleb: I have a question. If I keep my app free for one month, then in the next I change the price tier. Will It effect (charge the new price) the users who have downloaded the app in the first month? Is there any way to provide a Trial period for a Paid app?

Comment: @MihirOza You're asking for clarification on an 3-year old answer to a closed, off-topic question. I think the answer above and the linked text (I updated the link) fully explain the meaning of the Price Tier Effective Date and Price Tier End Date fields. If you can be specific about what you don't understand, I'm happy to help if I can, but I'm certainly not going to spend my time guessing at what you might want to know. Please read the linked document thoroughly before asking for additional help.